# Guest checkout, returning customer information from order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, sales-order, magento-2.1.10

How can I get (if possible) information about whether the order is a guest checkout and if it is a logged in customer, it is a returning customer?

edit:

Unfortunately the previously marked solution does not work in all cases. Sometimes even though a customer has already ordered the order collection return nothing.
I tried this alternative approach but it does not work as well:

```
<?php
// ...

private function getCustomerType(Order $order, Address $billingAddress = null, Address $shippingAddress = null)
{
    if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        return self::ORDER_TYPE_GUEST;
    }

    $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $this->getUserEmail($order, $billingAddress, $shippingAddress));
    /** @var Order\Item $firstItem */
    $firstItem = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();
    if($firstItem instanceof Order\Item) {
        if (!empty($firstItem->getId())) {
            return self::ORDER_TYPE_RETURN;
        }
    }
    return self::ORDER_TYPE_NEW;
}
```

Comment: returning customer means ?

Comment: he ordered already

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to determine the order type:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    const ORDER_TYPE_GUEST  = "guest checkout";
    const ORDER_TYPE_NEW    = "new customer";
    const ORDER_TYPE_RETURN = "returning customer";

    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ){
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    private function getCustomerType(Order $order)
    {
        if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            return self::ORDER_TYPE_GUEST;
        }

        $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory
                           ->create()
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                           ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $order->getCustomerEmail());
        if ($orderCollection->count()) {
            return self::ORDER_TYPE_RETURN;
        } else {
            return self::ORDER_TYPE_NEW;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out this works in most cases but not all. Sometimes even though a customer has ordered already the orderCollection returns null :/